# how to check file is present in directory using if condition

Tags: file, unix

in my code. file has specific name where i need to search in a directory whether the file received today or not . so this is my condition:

```
if [-f "OIS_GCU.$presentday*]
then echo "exists"
else
echo "no"
```

here the presentday is file date format which i have declared before and rest file name will have some randome digits. like OIS_GCU.20180310012345. even though file is there it is skipping and printing else. Please help

Comment: In a comment to @slashpau you remark that you do have a space after `presentday`. Please correct your post, showing the space, the closing-`"` (when present) and explain `*` (do you have a wildcard there, and is at most one hit guaranteed?)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing space between square bracelets and if statement not closed

```
if [ -f "OIS_GCU.$presentday" ]
then
    echo "exists"
else
    echo "no"
fi
```

Comment: Did you try the way I posted above? Also try echo and see what is in the variable presentday